# Preventing duplicate items in a knockout.js observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I run a timed loop which fetches data asynchronously from the server and updates an observable array. I thought that this would prevent dups but it doesn't seem to. How can I prevent adding duplicates?

```
// Operations
self.addDevice = function (device) {
    if (device != null && ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(self.devices, device) < 0) {
        self.devices.push(device);
    } 
}
```

This is always returning true, as in the array does not contain the particular device (though it clearly does).

Comment: Use `ko.utils.arrayFirst` and pass a function to compare the items `by value`. See [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updates you get may have all the same values as objects you have in your array, but they're probably different objects, so a simple equality check will return false.  You'll have to supply a callback to test for equality yourself by comparing properties within the objects.

For example, if `a = {prop: 5}` and `b = {prop: 5}`, then `a == b` returns false.  You need to pass in a function to `ko.utils.arrayFirst` or `ko.utils.arrayFilter` like

```
var newItem = new Item();

ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function(existingItem, newItem) {
    return existingItem.prop == newItem.prop;
}
```